# Adding blank(null) field to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to adding a column into a table whose fields are empty, neither "0" nor "null".

```
"ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD COLUMN `newcolumn` INT NOT NULL"
```

makes all fields "0". I also tried `DEFAULT=''` option but then the column doesn't even added. So how to achieve really blank fields?

Comment: You have set default value for existing data of INTEGER type

Comment: i don't think an integer couldn't be a number nor null.

Comment: Does "null" in mysql table mean the null constant or the word null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this and works.

```
ALTER TABLE  `__test` ADD  `test_column` INT NULL
```

Comment: OP said: 'neither "0" nor "null".'

Comment: I think i misunderstood the "null". Does it mean `echo $column` (suppose it retrieves the null field) gives n-u-l-l word or the null constant?

Comment: NULL means nothing. It's not an empty string, it's less than that. It's the lack of an assigned value. The equivalent in PHP would be a variable that isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**.

The only valid values for the INTEGER column are numbers and NULL. You cannot simply define `DEFAULT ''` since `''` is already an empty string.

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD COLUMN `newcolumn` INT DEFAULT 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a6e2d/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an INT field. It may be NULL or 0, but it can't be the empty string, since that's a string, and not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified `NOT NULL`. This means that the fields cannot be null i.e. empty.

If you want "really blank" fields, then change the column specification to:

```
 "ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD COLUMN `newcolumn` INT NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code:

```
create table test( a int )

insert into test(a) values (1),(2),(3)

ALTER TABLE test ADD b INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```